# WCF client unable to establish secure connection during machine boot

Tags: c#, wcf

In our setup we have a WCF client in a windows service that needs to request configuration from a central server hosting a WCF endpoint. Client/Server communication works like a charm when the client machine is fully up and running but fails during boot.
below is the Exception throw:

> EXCEPTION THROWN: System.TimeoutException: Client is unable to finish
> the security negotiation within the configured timeout
> (00:00:19.9839990).  The current negotiation leg is 1
> (00:00:19.8689925).---> System.TimeoutException: The request channel
> timed out attempting to send after 00:00:19.8689925. Increase the
> timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the
> SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation
> may have been a portion of a longer timeout

The channel connection is secured with `var binding = new WSHttpBinding("SecureWsHttpBinding")` and Certificates.
I have tried with various increasing `OperationTimeout` values from 60s to 120s with basically the same result.
At the time when the Exception occur the network card is up and running.

Do anybody know why this is happening under these conditions? Do SecureWsHttpBinding require some windows services to run?

Comment: There are many possibilities to cause this situation, most likely caused by a firewall, you need to check your firewall.

Comment: @DingPeng client machine do not have windows firewall enabled.

Comment: Can you provide some information about the WCF configuration? I need to determine whether there is a problem with your configuration.